# storage-class specifier 'register' in c99 semantics

Tags: c, c99

I'm a foreigner reading C99, while a sentence (in 6.7.1) makes me confused:

- '(A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class
  specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as
  possible.) **The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
  implementation-defined.**'

How should I parse the second sentence :

- The extent to, **which such suggestions are effective**, is implementation-defined.
- The extent, **to which such suggestions are effective**, is implementation-defined.

which one is better?

Does that means an implementation has full powers to decide how to deal with *register*, even with a termination of translation?

Thanks.

Comment: The underlying phrase is "X to the extent", so in relative-clause form it's "the extent { to which X ... }".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No -- the extent to which the suggestions are effective, is implementation defined, but the effect of the code as a whole is not.

To put it slightly differently, when/if you put `register` into your code (where allowed), the compiler can completely ignore it -- and I feel obliged to add that nearly all reasonably modern compilers *will*.

Nonetheless, the mere presence of `register` won't prevent the code from compiling, unless you try to apply it somewhere it's not allowed (e.g., to a global variable).

Bottom line: don't use it, but don't worry about removing it from code that already has it either. It's a waste of time and effort, but with reasonably modern compilers a completely harmless one.

Comment: The compiler can't *entirely* ignore `register`. It's a constraint violation (which requires a diagnostic) to apply the `&` operator to an object with register storage class. I think there are a few other examples too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix up `register` variables with registers of the CPU. These are not the same.

`register` has the purpose to allow for optimizations. Taking the address of a such a variable is forbidden and as a consequence such a variable can never alias, the compiler always masters its latest value. Thus it can realize such a variable easily as a CPU register or an assembler immediate, for example.

As a particular subcase there are `const` qualified `register` variables that can't be altered by the program directly nor behind the scenes by some other code that would access it through a pointer. Only such variables can easily be guaranteed to be constant  through out the whole program execution.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to assume that *any* variable declared `const` is not modified, because doing so has undefined behaviour.  `register` is not necessary.

Comment: @caf, the compiler is allowed, you aren't :) Modifying a `const` declared object is "just" undefined behavior. Taking the address of a `register` variable is a constraint violation, which is a much stronger property. `register` is a service provided to the programmer to ease assertions about the code.

Comment: I am not sure what you are implying by saying *"the compiler is allowed, you aren't"*.  The programmer doesn't need to assume; the programmer knows.

Comment: @caf, I was referring to your phrase "the compiler is allowed". And no, the programmer doesn't know in general. Perhaps *you* know in the code that you are writing that for a particular variable you are never taking the address, pass it to a function that you don't master where it will be subject to a `const` cast and modified. I don't. This is UB, right, but under all compilers I know I will never notice the fault for local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Register is an old keyword. Basically it is a hint to an optimizer telling that it is better to use register for storing this variable. The pharse that you are mentioning means that compiler can treat this hint in any way it wants. In our days of optimizing compilers, its meaning and value for 99% is nothing.